# How to modify correct table value's color display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made the following code to display the table value color on the screen according to the range of each substance.
However, since the index is given differently while calling the function for each row, the colors are displayed only up to the 6th row, and even this does not fit the range, and the wrong color is displayed.
From row 7, there is a problem that only #666666 color appears.
Please correct the code to display the color according to the material range.

```
function DashBoard() {
    const limit = [
        [15, 35, 75],
        [30, 80, 150],
        [0.03, 0.09, 0.15],
        [0.03, 0.06, 0.2],
        [0.02, 0.05, 0.15],
        [2, 9, 15]
    ];
    
    const textColorChange = (value, index, colors) => {
        const ranges = limit[index];
        
        console.log(index, ranges);
    
        if (!ranges) {
            return colors[colors.length - 1];
        }
        
        for (let i = 0; i <= ranges.length; i++) {
            if (value <= ranges[i]) {
                return colors[i];
            }
            if (ranges[i] < value && (i === ranges.length - 1 || value <= ranges[i + 1])) {
                return colors[i + 1];
            }
        }
        return colors[colors.length - 1];
    };

    return (
        <Style.Table>
            <Style.Title className="caption-text" onToggle={tabHandler}>{airTitle}</Style.Title>
            <Style.StyledTable>

                <tbody>
                    {regionList.map((region, index) => (
                        <tr key={index}>
                            <td className="region">{region.sidoNm}</td>
                            <td className="number" style={{ color: textColorChange(region.avgNow, index, ["#2359C5", "#01B56E", "#F5C932", "#DA3539", "#666666"]) }}>{region.avgNow}</td>
                            <td className="number" style={{ color: textColorChange(region.avgTd, index, ["#2359C5", "#01B56E", "#F5C932", "#DA3539", "#666666"]) }}>{region.avgTd}</td>
                            <td className="number" style={{ color: textColorChange(region.max, index, ["#2359C5", "#01B56E", "#F5C932", "#DA3539", "#666666"]) }}>{region.max}</td>
                            <td className="number" style={{ color: textColorChange(region.min, index, ["#2359C5", "#01B56E", "#F5C932", "#DA3539", "#666666"]) }}>{region.min}</td>
                            <td className="number" style={{ color: textColorChange(region.avgYd, index, ["#2359C5", "#01B56E", "#F5C932", "#DA3539", "#666666"]) }}>{region.avgYd}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </Style.StyledTable>
        </Style.Table>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your `limit` array has length `6` that works for your first 6 `<tr>` rows because you are using index of row array `regionList` which has more elements, so your `if (!ranges) {` triggers and returns the last elemet's color from `colors` array.

Comment: @UmerAbbas Thanks for your advice but I don't understand what you mean. So please give me in detail.

Comment: when your `<tr>` index is greater than `5` if you dry run your code, you will see it will always assign `ranges` as `undefined` because your `limit` array is of fixed length `6` meaning it does not contain any ranges for index 6 and above, so `return colors[colors.length - 1];` line of code executes and you get same color for all the remaining `<tr>` but if you still want to return a different color you can use modulus operator in this line, `return colors[index % colors.length];`. I just pointed out the problem with your code, I really don't understand what you trying to achieve.

Comment: @UmerAbbas I almost have a complete solution! Your advice is very helpful~

Comment: Glad to hear, have an amazing rest of the day!